# Problem in reading Excel file from shared google drive

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-drive-api

I have a strange problem opening an excel file in python from google drive.
I have to open two similar xlsx files from the drive and for the first workbook everything is fine, the second one shows the following error:

ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

Here is my code:

```
    #load the excel file

#load the first dataset
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qmgNhl_KjT6V4_MLfVA9OtlnV3ZCl3kw/edit#gid=344712875"
file_id = url.split("/")[-2]
path1 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file_id

sp500_price = pd.read_excel(path1)

#load the second dataset
url1 = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bxrKbUF6siR1JH8LhGr9Q2l1sN3R1qWB/edit#gid=926028981"
file_id1 = url1.split("/")[-2]
path2 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file_id1

sp500_esg = pd.read_excel(path2)
```

any ideas?

Comment: It seems Pandas cannot determine the file format of the second Excel file. To resolve this, you can explicitly specify the engine to use when reading the Excel file.

You can try adding the engine parameter to the pd.read_excel() function and set it to either "openpyxl" or "xlrd" depending on the engine that you have installed.

`sp500_esg = pd.read_excel(path2, engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: You may also want to check what file type the second google doc is saved as (i.e. xlsx, xls, xlsm) and then specify the file type

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried to specify both engines and I still have the error. with "openpyxl" it says that it "is not a zip file"  @C_Turbo

Comment: Did you figure out the file type of the second file?

Comment: Yes, it was an excel with a formula retrieved from Eikon and it seems that once you change the formula python is not able to read it as a normal Exel file.

Answer (score 1):

It was an excel with a formula retrieved from Eikon and it seems that once you change the formula python is not able to read it as a normal Exel file.